# Mouse pointer system default hand icon (Flixel game-making library)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flixel

How to change mouse pointer to system default hand/pointer icon hovering button, for example?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.kirupa.com/flash/changing_mouse_cursor.htm

```
package 
{
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.ui.MouseCursor;
} 

// function
quitButton = new FlxButton(10, 10, "Quit", onQuit);
quitButton.onOver = function():void { Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON; };
quitButton.onOut = function():void { Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO; };
```